# How to output from staticmethod of class in Python?

Tags: python, function

I have class which has staticmethod. I have if-else statements in this function and i must to count some conditions.
This conditions looks like:

```
def count(a):
    success, overall = 0, 0
    for i in range(a):
        if i%3 == 0:
            success += 1
            overall += 1
        elif i%3 == 1:
            overall +=1
        elif i%3 == 2:
            success += 1
            overall += 1
    return success, overall
```

and work well without this class and function. But I need a table to output this data. How to do so? I tried to log every value, but it goes wrong and seems to complicated. How to output success and overall from class and static method?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `but it goes wrong and seems to complicated.` we can't help you if you don't tell us the problem. what did you try? what errors did you get? (add this to the question, also add the full stack trace of teh exception if any) what exactly do you want to get?

Comment: The term static method might be a bit ambiguous, because it has a slightly different meaning in Python, than it has in other OOP languages. Are you referring to a method wrapped by `@staticmethod` or do you just mean a method which is a class member? Please provide a full Minimal Example.

Comment: Btw, this code is a bit messy. `overall` always just returns the value of `a`. And success could be computed much easier mathematically, i.e. without a loop.

Comment: You mention you want to return the values as a table, mind giving us an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

## Improvement of your `count()` method

Not exactly related to your question, but I think it should be mentioned first: Your `count()`-method could be improved by getting rid of the expensive for-loop:

```
def bad_count(a):
    success, overall = 0, 0
    for i in range(a):
        if i%3 == 0:
            success += 1
            overall += 1
        elif i%3 == 1:
            overall +=1
        elif i%3 == 2:
            success += 1
            overall += 1
    return success, overall


def better_count(a: int) -> int:
    b = a - 1
    successes = int(2*((b - b % 3) / 3) + {0: 1, 1: 1, 2:2}[b % 3])
    return successes, a
```

## How to use it as `@staticmethod`

And this is how you define and call staticmethods in Python:

```
from typing import Tuple


class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def static_count(a: int) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        b = a - 1
        successes = int(2*((b - b % 3) / 3) + {0: 1, 1: 1, 2:2}[b % 3])
        
        return successes, a


for i in range(5):
    assert(MyClass.static_count(i) == bad_count(i))
```